# sql server: access remotely vs locally

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a sql server database instance running in one location (let's say New York).
Then I have a process which writes to the database located in the same region. This exposes an API which is accessed from a process running in a remote location (let's say London).

The question is which is a better setup?
a) The setup as shown above.
b) The remote process directly writing to the database.

Also, would option (b) hold onto the DB connections longer or is the SQL Server API smart enough to block the DB only after the data has transferred over the wire? i.e. is there a higher chance of running into max connections with option (b)?

Comment: This question is very general and broad without much detail and as such can be hardly answered.

Comment: Not quite sure what additional information is needed. The question is whether inserts and updates done on a database via a process located in the same region and relayed to a remote process against having a remote process directly access the database. I'm looking for the pros and cons of each.

Comment: Check this https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252854/2224701